# How is the constrained maximization problem in the Ramsey model solved?

Tags: optimization, optimal-control, ramsey

Assuming that utility is forward discounted $ \rho $, lifetime utility = $  \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\rho t}u(c) \,dt   $.
And in continuous time, we also know that $ \dot{k} = y - (\delta + n)k - c$.

Given these two equations, our problem is:

$  \arg \max_{c}(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\rho t}u(c) \,dt) $ such that $  c = y - (\delta + n)k - \dot{k} $

How is this solved in an optimal control context?

Comment: Economic Growth, (The MIT Press) 2nd Edition
by Robert J. Barro (Author), Xavier I. Sala-I-Martin (Author)

Comment: Alecos, what part of the book? And is there a pdf format? Or maybe you could summarize it in an answer, that would help...

Comment: What prior research have you done? Have you googled "ramsey problem continous time"?